# How can I call a python function that takes arguments from html?

Tags: python, html, apache, web, arguments

I want to program a web-interface for an e-mail server that runs apache.

The script needs to be able to browse to a specified path (i need argument passing for that), search the files in the folder for a string and list the folders content.

So, how can i pass arguments from an html webpage to my python script and call the corrosponding function?

For example, i have a textfield and onclick of the "Navigate" button i take the input of the field and call the `navigate_to(path)` method in my python script.

Comment: DEFINITELY use flask: http://flask.pocoo.org/. It is easy to use. Just follow the examples on the link

Comment: why use flask over cgi?

Comment: It is much simpler, I've tried cgi with no luck. flask saved me

Comment: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/ the docs

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way to do it.

Your question is broad and doesn't really explain a lot which leads me to believe you need to read up on a few things, but CGI sounds like an OK start.

Take a look at https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_cgi_programming.htm, make sure you understand how data is being sent / picked up by your script and take it from there.

The portion where you mention "call the navigate_to_(path) method" in your script will become obvious once you understand CGI, but it just narrows down to how you deal with arguments in your script.

Comment: I asked a similiar question yesterday which is more specific, but it barely got attention so i thought i asked something dumb that doesnt make sense. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45213148/how-do-i-call-a-python-function-with-parameters-in-cgi)
But i guess i will keep looking into cgi then, i thought it wasnt possible with it. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Why are you trying to make the file system accessible via html?

Comment: to give the admin a possibility to browse the server and display the files on it which he usually does by shell. is html not the correct way to go about this?
im not familiar with python and web developing quite yet, i've only worked with java so far.